# How to concatenate a query string safely in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

For example:

#### Query1

```
abc:='select * from table1';
```

#### Query2

```
result:='create view'||quote_ident(view1)||'as'||abc;
```

Comment: Didn't you ask an identical (and equally uninformative) question a day or two ago, then ignore replies to it? Yes, you did, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22039978/398670 . Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/tour then try again.

Comment: Yes. But i was trying without quote_ident for query1, as you said earlier. But getting an error near as. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to take a wild guess and assume you're trying to use dynamic SQL to create a view.

If so, use the `EXECUTE` statement.

```
abc    := 'select * from table1';
result := 'create view '||quote_ident(view1)||' as ' || abc;  
EXECUTE result;
```

Your query text looked OK except for the missing spaces, assuming that `view1` is a `text` parameter.

(In future: include PostgreSQL version, **exact text** of any error message, the full code you're using, etc).